# Why is Observable Subscribe Making My Class Empty

Tags: angular, typescript, express, rxjs

I have created a service, when the service is called and do a console log of the parameter in the subscriber it shows my class empty.  I have used Observable's in the past and I have never ran into this issue. If it serves me right the parameter can be any name. Code snippet below.

```
My service

export interface Products{
  _id: string,
  name: string
}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SearchService {

 
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  rootUrl = '/api'
  
   
  searchProducts(query:string) {
    console.log("Does it get  my  searchProducts");
    return this.http.post<{payload: Array<Products>}>(this.rootUrl + '/getProducts', {payload: query}, {
     
     headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application.json'})       
    }).pipe(
       map(data => data.payload)
     
    );
        
  }
```

}

My Component.ts

```
sendData(event:any){

let query:string = event.target.value;

   this.searchService.searchProducts(query.trim()).subscribe(results =>{   
     console.log(results);  //results is a empty array
   });
 }
```

Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Have you tried removing the pipe to make sure there is something in the response?

Comment: It’s application/json with a forward slash not a period and it’s added automatically so you can probably omit those headers entirely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `return` before `data.payload` like this:

```
searchProducts(query:string) {
    console.log("Does it get  my  searchProducts");
    return this.http.post<{payload: Array<Products>}>(this.rootUrl + '/getProducts', {payload: query}, {
     
     headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application.json'})       
    }).pipe(
       map(data => return data.payload)
     
    );
        
  }
```

If still doesn't work then it may be blank because of how you treat the request data. You're saying that the post will receive data in this format:

```
{payload: Array<Products>}
```

An object with a parameter with an array of products, and may not match the real data format coming from the API.

If you know that it will be an array then change for `<Products[]>` and if you know that will be an object with an array inside try `<{Products[]}>` or `<{payload: Products[]}>`, if don't work try to remove the `<>` and everything inside.

And the same applies to how you send the request body if the API doesn't receive in `{payload: String}` format then doesn't do what you asking for.

Comment: Hi removing the Array from the parameter and the Product class was a step in the right direction I am able to see my payload when I console.log on the back end I was getting undefined before, like so router.post('/getProducts',  async(req, res) =>{ let payload=req.body.payload;. console.log()    I still don't have a response so I'm still working trying to figure this out.

Comment: @user2280852 in the browser open DevTools with F12 and go to the network then search for the post request by tipping `getProducts` or just searching one by one. After, check the payload and the response of the request to see if you send the payload data to the backend and if the backend returns data in the response body.

Answer (score 0):

Does your API response contain a field called payload? If so, does it have a value?

I recommend moving your console log up a level so that you can see what the API response is and what fields it has. Something like this,

```
searchProducts(query:string) {
  console.log("Does it get  my  searchProducts");
  return this.http.post<{payload: Array<Products>}>(this.rootUrl + '/getProducts', {payload: query}, {
 
   headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application.json'})       
  }).pipe(
   map(data => {
     console.log('API Response => ', data);
     return data.payload
   })
 
);
```

}

Comment: Hi yes there is a payload request with a value, the value is what ever I type into the input but the response payload i s empty.

Comment: I did what was suggested this is output from console log API Response =>  {payload: Array(0) which is what I get in the chrome network payload response. I'm  going back and forth of whether the issue is front end or back end

Comment: If the API isn’t returning the value you expect, that seems like an issue with the API. Is it an API you wrote? Is there documentation that could point you toward the expected response payload?

Comment: The code I wrote which checks if whats in the payload exist in mongoose db

Comment: The user type into text box to search db for a particular product if the products exist it should just shows on the view for now until I add more functionality

Comment: Hello changing the service to return this.http.post<{payload: Products[]}>(this.rootUrl + '/getProducts', {payload: query}, I do have a response in the payload. Still working on mongoose aspect of my application.  Thank you so very much